# JavaScript (or JS+PHP) Terminal Client

Tags: php, javascript, ssh, terminal

Does anyone know of a JS-based terminal client? Either something that initiates an SSH connection with a remote host or even something that simply communicates with a remote PHP script to execute commands and retrieve output. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Anyterm](http://anyterm.org/), it uses a XmlHttpRequest channel to communicate with a daemon that uses a pseudo-terminal to communicate with a shell or other application.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/ looks interesting as a base.

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsterminal

but you'd have to write your own commands to connect with the host

Answer (score 1):

Shell in a box could be used also with a small Asus EEE-PC:

http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/

It works great also for virtual machines in a cloud.

Answer (score 0):

So far [JSDom Shell](http://www.webessence.nl/projects/jsdom.ui.console/index.html) is the only thing I have found, which seems relatively barebones but practical. If there are any other more substantial options, feel free to share!