# Get Linux screen session with PHP

Tags: php, linux, ssh

My server always has a screen session running and I'd like to display everything that's visible to a user connected to the screen session, on a web page.

I know how to run SSH commands and get their output in PHP, but I can't seem to find how to latch on to the screen session and get the visible screen, and send that back to PHP.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294945/javascript-or-jsphp-terminal-client could get you started I think

Comment: You want something like a VNC connection? To see on your machine what a physical user sees on the other machine's screen? 
Or do you want that when the other user interacts with the screen session, every character is sent to your machine using PHP, so that you can display it on a webpage?

Comment: I don't need interaction (yet). I want to get what the user would see if they were connected to the screen session (via VNC for example) but as text I can format on my page.

Answer (score 0):

If that screen session is a Linux terminal, for example, the only way I see it is by logging the terminal into a file and then access that file using PHP and print it to your webpage.

See if this helps you getting started: https://ayaz.wordpress.com/2006/11/19/script1-logging-terminal-sessions-to-files/

(In Windows, if you use putty, I believe that you can also save the contents to a file)

Comment: It looks like a start but surely since I can disconnect and reconnect to a screen session, the screen in the session must be stored somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I'm not following you right now... You're talking about disconnecting and reconnecting from your machine to the other user's machine? The session is always being stored in the file. You just have to access it.

Comment: Which file are screen sessions stored in on a RHEL machine? I basically just want to cat that file and grab the output. I want to do this without attaching it if possible.

Comment: They are /dev/ttyX where X is a the terminal number. But you just can't cat them because it's a device file and doesn't store data. You could try running tail -f /dev/ttyX but I'm not sure that would work. The last link I gave you lists a program called conspy which will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As long as php is not running in safe mode, you could use phpshell to run screen.

http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/

Linux.com article about it.

http://archive09.linux.com/feature/127056

How to share a screen session. Note that the host has to allow and add the viewer.

http://eric.lubow.org/2010/system-administration/sharing-a-screen-session/

if you aren't using screen, you can use this to monitor the session.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-make-typescript-of-terminal-session/

here's another stackoverflow answer on how to monitor terminal sessions.

[Linux Terminal: how to capture or watch other terminal session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353253/linux-terminal-how-to-capture-or-watch-other-terminal-session)

Comment: I believe that his problem is to "see" the current opened terminal screen. PHPShell is very useful, but it just opens a new shell connection.

Comment: He said screen. Which I assume the user is running screen which can share sessions.

Comment: Also terminals in linux are files. You can always view them if you have root access.