# SSH terminal using JS, HTML5 and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ssh, terminal

I'm looking for a solution like [GateOne](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne) that i could install on a server which support PHP for which i have no ssh connection. It also support Python but i can't execute anything on it without an actual SSH access. That mean it would have to work just by dropping it into a folder.

I've seen [JavaScript (or JS+PHP) Terminal Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294945/javascript-or-jsphp-terminal-client) but the solutions seem outdated.

For example i'd like to be able to execute a simple `ln -s ./dir1 ./dir2` to create a symbolic link.

Comment: Why not just use a host that provides SSH?

Comment: @ceejayoz Because i've already paid a whole year at a host that doesn't provide SSH in their basic offer =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found out that [codiad](http://codiad.com/) which i now use has a terminal way better than phpshell.
I went for that solution. It allows to manage web projects too but i think it's the most advanced terminal currently available that doesn't need any installation through command line.

Comment: If you ever need it outside of Codiad, the author released the Terminal plugin as a [standalone](https://github.com/Fluidbyte/PHP-jQuery-Terminal-Emulator) version.

Answer (score 6):

I think you don't actually want SSH. Maybe you should try a simple php shell like http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/ if you really just want to run non-interactive commands?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a php ssh client that use php and xterm, you can take the source code on the github page https://github.com/roke22/PHP-SSH2-Web-Client

Please send some feedback too.

I hope that help you.